# Im trying to Insert a result field from a previous Select using SQL SERVER with PHP and is not working

Tags: php, sql-server

```
$idcliente=$_POST['clientes'];

$query = "SELECT Nombre FROM [RMSG].[dbo].[Clientes_Corte]
    where IDCliente =$idcliente AND Status = 0"; 

$result = sqlsrv_query($estadocon, $query);

if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $insertar="INSERT into Registro_Corte
             (IDCliente,NombreCliente,Descripcion,Lote,Yarda,Fecha)
  values($idcliente,".$row['Nombre'].",'$descrip','$lote','$yarda','$fecha')";

  $recurso=sqlsrv_prepare($estadocon, $insertar)or die('Error');
    if(sqlsrv_execute($recurso)){
      print '<script language="JavaScript">'; 
      print 'alert("Registro Creado Exitosamente!!")'; 
      print '</script>';
    else{
      print '<script language="JavaScript">'; 
      print 'alert("Error al Guardar Registro!!")'; 
      print '</script>';
     }
} else { 
    echo "No se encontro el Nombre del Cliente"; 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You are going to have to do better than "it isn't working". We don't know what that means. Do you get an error message? Is the data incorrect? You also desperately need to read about and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables come to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Here is a great place to get some ideas about how to improve this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If the `INSERT` query is failing, use `print_r(sqlsrv_errors())` to see the reason.

Comment: Hi again thanks for replying I just use sqlsrv_errors like you said and i got an error like this:  Incorrect syntax near 'Elizabeth' and that is the field from the first select. Something is wrong in the way I wrote it ?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a string, your field 'Nombre' should be in inside single quotes, like this:

```
$insertar="INSERT into Registro_Corte
    (IDCliente,NombreCliente,Descripcion,Lote,Yarda,Fecha)
    values($idcliente,'".$row['Nombre']."','$descrip','$lote','$yarda','$fecha')";
```